# PHP PDO sql query and results

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm having issues implementing an SQL query using PDO.

```
$friend_emails = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT User2
                    FROM members
                    WHERE User1 = '$user'
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT User1
                    FROM members
                    WHERE User2 = '$user'");
$friend_emails->execute();

for($i=0; $row = $friend_emails->fetch(); $i++) { 
    echo "foo";
}
```

"foo" doesn't show at all. I var_dumped $row and $friend_emails->fetch() both of which are a

```
boolean false
```

so I'm not exactly sure why that is, I thought it would return an array of the data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: After the `execute()` call check `$friend_emails->errorInfo()` for any error messages. Besides, if you use a `prepare()` statement, you should not insert the dynamic values there, but in the `execute()` later on.

Comment: BTW, why use `prepare` when you are using String Interpolation and not really `prepare` ing your statement?

Comment: @Sirko I added the ->errorInfo(), do I need to echo it? If not then there are no errors.

Comment: @CoreyThompson `errorInfo()` returns an array with information about what went wrong. You could use `var_dump()` to have a look at it outputs in debugging. In a productive system you should have a more sophisticated error handling.

Comment: Nevermind, my issue was in the SQL, sorry. I'm now using the prepare/execute properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use while here

```
while($row = $friend_emails->fetch()) { 
   echo "foo";
}
```

Your for loop will never execute because

```
for($i=0; $row = $friend_emails->fetch(); $i++)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // here $i is not present
```

The correct format will be

```
for($i=0; $i <= count($friend_emails->fetch()); $i++)
```

Comment: So should I use the while loop or the new for loop?

Comment: @CoreyThompson You can try both, but while is better than for, for fetching records from db.

Comment: Just realised my issue was an SQL issue, however the while loop is better so I'm using that. Thanks!

Comment: `count($friend_emails->fetch())` will return **1**... And it will run only once... **Only the `while` loop is applicable here**...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is **wrong variable names**.

a variable returned by `$pdo->prepare()` contains not a single email, but PDO statement. Thus it ought to be named accordingly.
Also you are not using prepared statements while you **should**

So, mo make this code consistent and readable:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT User2 FROM members WHERE User1 = ?
        UNION
        SELECT DISTINCT User1 FROM members WHERE User2 = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare();
$stmt->execute(array($user,$user));
$emails = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)
```

and now you have your emails in a convenient array which you can iterate over:

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    echo $email;
}
```

Also you have to configure your PHP and PDO as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858) to be able to see all the errors if any occurred (as query error could be also quite possible reason for the whole code fail)

Answer (score -1):

change your code to

```
$friend_emails = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT User2
                    FROM members
                    WHERE User1 = :user
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT User1
                    FROM members
                    WHERE User2 = :user");
$friend_emails->execute(array('user' => $user));
```

Comment: I have now changed it to this, however the for loop still doesn't output "things" :(

Comment: My error was in the SQL, sorry my bad. Thanks for your help and I am now using this code.